# Python's NLTK documentation

Tags: python, nltk

Where can I found the offline documentation for NLTK? It's not in usr/share/doc, where I mostly find docs of Python modules. And there is no nltk-doc package that can be installed.

Comment: What's your distribution and what sort of documentation are you expecting to be found? Just a `README` or something more expansive?

Comment: @cwgem: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I'd like to find an API for the module. The online version is the http://nltk.org/py-modindex.html, which includes an explanation and the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so it definitely doesn't come with any package. However it can be built. So first:

```
sudo apt-get install python-epydoc
```

This is needed to build the documentation. Then I made this script to automate the build process for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

NLTK_VERSION=$(python -c 'import nltk; print nltk.__version__')
NLTK_URL=$(python -c 'import nltk; print nltk.__url__')
EPYDOC_OPTS = --name=nltk --navlink="nltk ${NLTK_VERSION}"\
              --url=${NLTK_URL} --inheritance=listed --debug

# Rebuild from scratch
[[ -e ~/python-nltk-docs ]] && rm -rf ~/python-nltk-docs

mkdir ~/python-nltk-docs
epydoc ${EPYDOC_OPTS} -o ~/python-nltk-docs /usr/share/pyshared/nltk
```

This will drop html docs into `~/python-nltk-docs` for your viewing. I basically pulled this together from their [doc Makefile](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/doc/Makefile).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did, get the NLTK website code from their Github. This way I could do 'search' on the API documentation also.

https://github.com/nltk/nltk.github.com